# questions about quantum groups

Tags: quantum-groups

I am reading Lusztig's book [Introduction to quantum groups](http://books.google.com/books?id=HKPjCUiOUQ0C&printsec=frontcover&dq=introduction+to+quantum+groups+lusztig&hl=en&ei=UrWtTeeNKIfZgQewic3sCw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false). I have a question on page 3. In the fourth line of section 1.2.2, it is said that $'f \otimes 'f$ is associative. I don't know why.

I think that $((x_1\otimes x_2)(x'_1\otimes x'_2))(x''_1\otimes x''_2)  = v^{|x_2||x'_1|}(x_1x'_1\otimes x_2x'_2) \otimes (x''_1\otimes x''_2)$ 
$= v^{|x_2||x'_1|+|x_2x'_2||x''_1|}x_1x'_1x''_1\otimes x_2x'_2x''_2$. But it seems that $(x_1\otimes x_2)((x'_1\otimes x'_2)(x''_1\otimes x''_2))$ does not equal this. Why $((x_1\otimes x_2)(x'_1\otimes x'_2))(x''_1\otimes x''_2) = (x_1\otimes x_2)((x'_1\otimes x'_2)(x''_1\otimes x''_2))$?

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your exponent $|x_2|\cdot|x_1'|+|x_2x_2'|\cdot|x_1''|$ is correct. The exponent for the other grouping is $|x_2'|\cdot|x_1''|+|x_2|\cdot|x_1'x_1''|$. To show that these are equal, you need the two facts that the product is bilinear and that $|xy|=|x|+|y|$ (corresponding to $'\mathbf f_\nu'\mathbf f_{\nu'}\subset'\mathbf f_{\nu+\nu'}$ at the bottom of page 2):

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
&&
|x_2|\cdot|x_1'|+|x_2x_2'|\cdot|x_1''|
\\
&=&
|x_2|\cdot|x_1'|+(|x_2|+|x_2'|)\cdot|x_1''|
\\
&=&
|x_2|\cdot|x_1'|+|x_2|\cdot|x_1''|+|x_2'|\cdot|x_1''|
\\
&=&
|x_2'|\cdot|x_1''|+|x_2|\cdot|x_1'|+|x_2|\cdot|x_1''|
\\
&=&
|x_2'|\cdot|x_1''|+|x_2|\cdot(|x_1'|+|x_1''|)
\\
&=&
|x_2'|\cdot|x_1''|+|x_2|\cdot|x_1'x_1''|\;.
\\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Comment: Nice answer. Thanks.